# Map enums to Dagger injected classes (MapBinder equivalent)

Tags: android, dagger

I'm trying to inject a class at runtime using a factory to map enums to class types, But I'm running into an issue where it will throw an error when I try to inject it.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No inject registered for members/com.example.android.push.DefaultPushHandlerStrategy. You must explicitly add it to the 'injects' option in one of your modules.

public class PushFactory {
    private Map<PushType, Class<? extends PushHandlerStrategy>> classMap = new HashMap<PushType, Class<? extends PushHandlerStrategy>>();

    @Inject
    public PushFactory() {
        classMap.put(PushType.DEFAULT, DefaultPushHandlerStrategy.class);
        classMap.put(PushType.VIDEOS, VideosPushHandlerStrategy.class);
        classMap.put(PushType.MESSAGE, MessagePushHandlerStrategy.class);
    }

    public PushHandlerStrategy getPushHandlerStategy(PushType type){
        Class<? extends PushHandlerStrategy> klazz = classMap.get(type);
        if(klazz == null){
            klazz = DefaultPushHandlerStrategy.class;
        }
        ObjectGraph graph = App.getApplication().getObjectGraph();
        return graph.get(klazz); // this line throws the exception
    }
}
```

Basically, what I'm trying to achieve is instantiating a strategy based on some data that comes in a GCM push.

I DO have the following registered in a module.

```
@Module(
    injects = {
        PushFactory.class,
        PushBroadcastReceiver.class
    },
    complete = false,
    library = false
)
public class PushModule {
}
```

Any ideas what's wrong with my approach?

Edit:

I was able to achieve what I wanted by injecting providers, but it seems a bit cumbersome. Any way around this?

```
public class PushFactory {
    private Map<PushType, Provider<? extends  PushHandlerStrategy>> providerMap = new HashMap<PushType, Provider<? extends PushHandlerStrategy>>();

    @Inject
    public PushFactory(Provider<DefaultPushHandlerStrategy> d, Provider<VideosPushHandlerStrategy> v, Provider<MessagePushHandlerStrategy> m) {
        providerMap.put(PushType.DEFAULT, d);
        providerMap.put(PushType.VIDEOS, v);
        providerMap.put(PushType.MESSAGE, m);
    }

    public PushHandlerStrategy getPushHandlerStrategy(PushType type){
        Provider<? extends  PushHandlerStrategy> provider = providerMap.get(type);
        if(provider == null){
            provider = providerMap.get(PushType.DEFAULT);
        }

        return provider.get();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original solution should be achievable but it seems like you're probably missing the injects definition of those class in your PushModule.  Since you're creating those objects using objectGraph.get(class) directly and not through field or constructor injection, without adding those classes to the injects Dagger cannot know that those classes are needed and will not create any plumbing for them and therefore will fail at runtime.

```
@Module(
    injects = {
        PushFactory.class,
        PushBroadcastReceiver.class,
        DefaultPushHandlerStrategy.class,
        VideosPushHandlerStrategy.class,
        MessagePushHandlerStrategy.class
    },
    complete = false,
    library = false
)
public class PushModule {
}
```